# Raphael multiple line in Text to shift downward rather than upward

Tags: jquery, raphael

I am trying to add dynamic text into the raphael paper using textArea and then copying it to the raphael text. The problem is when are multiple lines the raphael text tends to move the starting point upward. Is there a attribute or method i can use to shift the multiple line text to downward?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124763/raphael-js-and-text-positioning

Comment: @oyatek My question is not about alinging the text left,middle or right.  It is about move the next line downwards rather than reposition the first line upwards.

Comment: Read the first answer to that question in the above link -- it does in fact give an alignTop function. You need to use .getBBox()

Comment: @ChrisWilson I think you mean the last answer. yes, it is working for me.